# How to validate select box input in Laravel4

Tags: validation, select, input, laravel, laravel-4

Currently when I want to validate a select box I need to include all the values within the validation field.

```
public static $rules = array(
    'type' => array('required', 'in:a,b,c,d')
);
```

Is there a best practise way to do this using an array?

For example:
I have a long list of country names and want to include this as the validation list.
The hacky way of doing this would be something along the lines of:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'type' => array('required', 'in:'.implode(',', $countries))
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Just thinking about this - I could use a custom validation rule and add the array name as the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom is possible, but a exist-rule can also do the job. More details on http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-exists

Comment: Thanks. That only helps if we're using data from a database though

Comment: well, custom validation it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a select menu with an array like so:

```
$types = [ ''    => 'select a type',
          'one'  => 'type one',
          'a'    => 'type a' ];
```

And rules for validation like so:

```
$rules = ['type' => 'required'];
```

As the first key of $types is an empty string. Will output like this:

```
 <option value=''>select a type</option>
```

On validation the required rule will fail validation.

Assuming all options in the select menu are valid options.